# Will lazyloading or deferring load of products on a category page have negative SEO effect on the ranking of the category keyword?

Tags: seo, server, search-results, content

- Let's say I have a clothing store.
- In that store, I have a page for the "Shoes Category."
- By default, the server processes and outputs 50 products per paginated page of a category.
- In an effort to reduce server response time, I am considering lazyloading the products post-load or on-load, rather than having the server process and serve them.

#### Question

Will it hurt SEO ranking for "shoes" for this "Shoes Page" if the products are not present in the native HTMl response?

In other words, I've always assumed that having more "shoes"(though not necessarily having the word "shoes" anywhere in any of their titles) products on a category titled "Shoes Category" would somehow help relevance of "shoes" to this page and therefore lead to higher ranking on search engines.  Is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do for the best of both worlds if you're trying to go interactive and reduce server load is to not make text count as a separate HTTP request. Search engines rely on text from a web page in order to determine how to rank it.

In HTTP 1.1, images and text (html) are resources that can't be merged into a single request from a standard web server such as apache. For this reason, you'll want to load all of your HTML code first which includes all the text people want to see.

Then if you want to incorporate lazy-loading, then add javascript that causes the image from the server to be requested and loaded on page the moment the user scrolls to an area close to the image.

If you want to minimize burden on the server more and your images are small enough, consider merging them all into one or two images and use CSS sprites. Then only one image file is requested and for each image place-holder, only different image co-ordinates and sizes are specified in CSS so that the correct image is shown.

And don't forget... Allow browsers to cache requests with proper cache-control directives and the like.

Also, consider using webpagetest.org to test your category pages to see how the resources are requested from your server and how long it takes for each resource to be requested.

Comment: That's what makes this weird.  1.  50 products, only text really is the product titles, most of which do not contain keywords. Then again, that's almost the only text on the page besides header links, category description, and footer links.  2.  Google seems to see content that is lazy loaded by JS on load. Can be seen with PageSpeed Insights test as well as Schema Structured Data Tool Test.   So I am still confused it it counts towards on page SEO text or not if loaded on load by JS... :/ Thoughts?